# How can I include a new line everytime I append to a list?

Tags: python

The task is to create a 5x5 grid of "O"s inside one list. This is what I've written so far:

```
board = ["O"]

def lalala(lst):
    new_list = []
    for item in lst:
        new_list.append([item]*5)
    return new_list

print lalala(board)*5
```

and this is what it looks like now:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

How do I make it look like a grid, something like this (but everything still has to be in one list):

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

and NOT like this (codecademy doesn't accept this):

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

Codecademy suggests I use range() but I don't see how that will help.

Comment: Have you tried using the `zip()` function of Python? I am sure this will create the output which you're looking for since it's the same character for all. But I do think that the `range()` has to be used for code academy to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a list of list, you cannot control how the linefeeds are issued afterwards. I would control the output line by line, using `join` and artificially adding the higher level `[]` manually

How about:

```
z = lalala(board)
print("["+",\n ".join(str(z) for _ in range(5))+"]")
```

result:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

Comment: I never thought about adding the [] manually. wow, you think creatively!

Answer (score 2):

In a way, your code is already correct.  There is in fact a 5x5 list of lists containing Os.

The print statement just shows that list of lists on one line.

You could use *pprint* instead:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(board)
```

Comment: Whoa, never knew that function existed. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other users, I do not believe that you can create a list which is printed on multiple lines.
If the goal is simply to print the lines as a grid and you have to use the range() function then maybe you should try:

```
list1 = [['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
for y in range(0, len(list1)):
    print list1[y]
```

Obviously this is not the most efficient way to solve the problem as you could completely do without the range() function but it is the only way I see a range() function being used.

Comment: Why go through `range`, just `for sublist in list1: print sublist` is enough.

Comment: That's what I meant with "not the most effective way". But the original question stated that it should be done with range()

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line:

```
new_list = []
```

your final statement is trying to print an object of type `list`. How an object is printed is defined by how it is converted to string. This is normally ruled by  `__str__()` method, which for a built-in like `list` is immutable and cannot be changed to do something else.

In order to solve your problem properly define a class that works like a `list` and when multiplied (your `*5`) returns something that prints as you want it:

```
board = ["O"]

class Lala:
    def __init__(self, lalala, x):
        self.lalala = lalala
        self.x = x

    def __str__(self):
        res = '['
        for i in range(self.x):
            for l in self.lalala:
                if i != 0:
                    res += ' '
                res += str(l)
                if i != self.x-1:
                    res += ',\n'
        res += ']'
        return res

class Lalala(list):
    def __mul__(self, x):
        return Lala(self, x)


def lalala(lst):
    new_list = Lalala()
    for item in lst:
        new_list.append([item]*5)
    return new_list

print(lalala(board)*5)
```

this gives:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

Depending on your usage of `lalala(board)*5` you may need to define other methods (`__getitem__`, etc.) as well.